# Wordpress wpdb - insert records from uploaded large csv file in custom plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

I'm writing wordpress plugin that import records from uploaded CSV file. How it should work:

1. Select file from disk;
2. Click upload;
3. Script go through file and inserts records (column `postcode` is Unique), when `postcode` exists other fields are updated.

Now some code (simplified for this question):

```
///...
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while( ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE ){
   $searcher->wpdb->insert( $searcher->wpdb->prefix . "searcher_postcodes", array(
        "name"     => $row[1],
        "postcode" => $row[0],
        "state" => $row[2],
        "state_short" => $row[3],
        "city" => $row[4],
        "lat" => $row[5],
        "lng" => $row[6]
    ) );
    echo "<br><code>" . $searcher->wpdb->last_query . "</code>";
    if( $searcher->wpdb->insert_id > 0 ){
        $imported++;
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "failure";
    }
}
```

And almost everything is fine, but once on few records ive got:

> Importing 16348
>
> `INSERT INTO wp_searcher_postcodes (name, postcode, state, state_short, city, lat, lng) VALUES ('Marienwerder', '16348', 'Brandenburg', 'BB', 'Barnim', '52.85', '13.6')` success
>
> Importing 16352
>
> `INSERT INTO wp_searcher_postcodes (name, postcode, state, state_short, city, lat, lng) VALUES ('Marienwerder', '16348', 'Brandenburg', 'BB', 'Barnim', '52.85', '13.6')` failure

In second query i have data from previous query, and it failure. So not every. Is any way to queue or buffer, or something like that every query in wpdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for file encoding, i had same problem and changing file encoding work for me

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 1):

Code looks good, I guess. Maybe the problem is in your data. Try this to see, if lines are really unique in csv:

```
echo "<br>" . $row[0] . ": <code>" . $searcher->wpdb->last_query . "</code>";
```